# jQuery validation plugin - All inputs error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having some issues getting my code to work. The user can add more input boxes and I need them all to be validated. The strange this is that it works if i remove the messages part.

```
$("input.ing").each(function(){
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Input a number"
        }
    });         
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Resin

Edit: Found this jsFiddle that does what is want, but when I copy the code to a doc, it does not work! :(
http://jsfiddle.net/jYwJE/

Comment: Please let us know what error you get while using it. keep in mind that example use a javascript that you can have it from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js
if you did not include this file before using it, so include it and check result again.

Comment: As you can see by your jsFiddle, that's the code you should use to accomplish what you are asking.  You're going to have to perform some basic troubleshooting... check your file line-by-line against the jsFiddle, check the versions of all included files, etc.  Unless you can reproduce or demonstrate the problem here, there is nothing for us to do here... my answer would just be another working version of your jsFiddle.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What are your console errors?

Comment: You have not shown the code that creates these new fields.  Does it ensure that all fields have a **unique** `name`?  This is critical or the validate plugin will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quote OP:  "The user can add more input boxes and I need them all to be validated."

The following code is more specific than your jsFiddle.  It shows that when the user clicks a button, a new field called `newfield` is added to the form and then the [rules are added dynamically](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) to this new field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

    $('button#add').one('click', function () {
        var field = '<input type="text" name="newfield" /><br />';
        $('#myform').prepend(field);
        $('[name="newfield"]').rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "this new field is now required"
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/km6XE/**

The demo only shows how to add *one* new `input` field.  If you want the user to be able to add more `input` elements, you'll need to make sure your code creates a **unique** `name` for each new `input` or you'll break the Validate plugin.

Comment: +1. or you can just use class="required" and forget about adding rules - http://jsfiddle.net/u7j9V/

Comment: @politus, Thanks. That's true, it's equally as valid.  For me, it's a matter of preference, where I like to keep the HTML and JavaScript as separated as possible.  (I also think it's easier for the jQuery Validiate newbies to better see where the rules are coming from.)